# JavaFX best practise guide for small/medium/big desktop applications?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm learning **JavaFX + FXML** on a project developing a multi-window desktop application. Later aiming for some dependencies between those windows (a change in gui 1 refreshes gui 2, gui x ... ).

Now I'm wondering **how experienced javafx developers structure their projects?

How they use multi-windows?

How do they open and re-initialize already opened windows?

How do they handle this over all classes?

How do they handle database connections/sql calls?**

I'm trying to develop using some kind of the MVC pattern, using a package for each window:

```
ModelWindowname.java      -- Model
Windowname.fxml           -- View
Windowname.css            -- 
ControllerWindowname.java -- Controller
```

Then I had some trouble to find a way to initialize windows from different classes. I could solve this by creating custom loader objects and creating my own initialize-methods (examples below).

```
@FXML
void openGuiOne(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    /*
     * We don't put the FXMLLoader into try/catch blocks, so we throw the IOException.
     * Why? The user has no impact on what's going on here, so we can avoid the
     * overload on code and trace-information.
     */
    Stage oStage = null; 
    Parent oScene = null;

    // Check if the stage is already opened
    if (StageHandler.stageAlreadyOpened("gui_one") == false) {
        // if not, open a new window based on the One.fxml design and set some properties
        oScene = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/com/mytool/one/One.fxml")); // requires to throw IOException 
        oStage = new Stage();           
        oStage.setScene(new Scene(oScene));
        oStage.setTitle("One");
        oStage.setResizable(false);
        oStage.setX(475.0); // Set x-position of the window on startup
        oStage.setY(410.0);  // Set y-position of the window on startup
        oStage.show();

        // Look into StageHandler-Class for detailed information about the class 
        StageHandler.addStage("gui_one", oStage);

        // EventHandler - close only this window if it's closed
        oStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                StageHandler.delStage("gui_one");
            }
        });
    } else {
        // if window is already opened, pull it to the foreground
        StageHandler.getStage("gui_one").toFront();
    }
}
```

If I want to open gui_one from a button on another gui then the main gui, how do I do this? That's now how I'm doing it:

```
@FXML
void openGuiOne(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, SQLException {
    /*
     * We don't put the FXMLLoader into try/catch blocks, so we throw the IOException.
     * Why? The user has no impact on what's going on here, so we can avoid the
     * overload on code and trace-information.
     */
    Stage oStage = null;
    FXMLLoader oLoaderOne = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com/mytool/one/One.fxml"));

    // Check if the stage is already opened
    if (StageHandler.stageAlreadyOpened("gui_one") == false) {
        // if not, open a new window based on the One.fxml design and set some properties
        oStage = new Stage();           
        oStage.setScene(new Scene(oLoaderOne.load()));
        ControllerOne oControllerOne = oLoaderOne.getController();
        oStage.setTitle("One");
        oStage.setResizable(false);
        oStage.setX(475.0); // Set x-position of the window on startup
        oStage.setY(50.0);  // Set y-position of the window on startup

        oControllerOne.myInitialize("");

        oStage.show();

        // Look into StageHandler-Class for detailed information about the class 
        StageHandler.addStage("gui_one", oStage);

        // EventHandler - close only this window if it's closed
        oStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                StageHandler.delStage("gui_one");
            }
        });
    } else {
        // if window is already opened, pull it to the foreground
        StageHandler.getStage("gui_one").toFront();
    }
}
```

But do I always have to copy those plenty lines of code on each controller for each gui I'm able to open?
Well, due to the fact I have to change it on multiple places I wouldn't even think about it. But right now I didn't got a good idea how to handle this. I believe I'm fine with oop, I simply never created a desktop application using oop.

My impression on researching those questions so far: almost every second answer is like "this is the only way to go" but every answer is different.

I found this article [http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/best_practices/jfxpub-best_practices.htm] but unfortunately I couldn't find anything (trustful) else.
Are thre any small/mediuum/large professional open-source projects on javafx? My first attempt was to get a view into open source projects and how big projects are getting structured ... i couldn't find a desktop application yet.
Or does anyone know a best practise guide which I totally missed yet, and which is getting followed by more then just a few people?

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you should do is NOT trying to re-invent the wheel like so many people here. Have a look at one of the existing application frameworks for JavaFX, e.g. MVVMFX https://github.com/sialcasa/mvvmFX/wiki
Such an application framework will give you a solid structure for your project which you can build on.

Comment: I'm going to have a look on this. Thank you so far.

Comment: But what about now? This framework no longer being supported, and I would like to use pure JavaFX